# Apperance of runtime Infragistics UltraWebGrid different than in ultrawebgrid designer

Tags: css, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

!I'm trying to get an Infragistics UltraWebGrid to work with one of the Styles provided by Infragistics (Office2007Blue).

My problem is that the grid looks nice at design time (image1)
[image]

... but bad (and very different) at runtime (image 2).
[image]

The odd thing is that - judging by the runtime html source - it seems that the Office2007Blue style *is* actually applied (image 3)
[image]

but that the referenced UltraWebGrid stylesheet file ig_grid_opt.css specifies an *orange* header image (images/office_grid_header.jpg) for the TH class, where I am expecting something blueish.

In the style's Image folder there is a different file (images/iguwg_header.gif) which seems much more suitable (it is blue!) than the office_grid_header.jpg image.

Have I configured my grid wrong, or is this an Infragistics style glitch?

EDIT: I cross-posted this question at the Infragistics web site and I think someone is looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infragistics engineer replied today confirming that this is in fact an incorrect image reference in the 
`Styles/Office2007Blue/ig_grid_opt.css` file.

According to them the correct image should be `igg_header.gif`

The css snippet below illustrates the fix. I am assuming they will fix this in later releases.

```
THEAD.igtbl_Office2007BlueHeader TR TH, 
TFOOT.igtbl_Office2007BlueHeader TR TH, TBODY.igtbl_Office2007BlueHeader TR TH
{
   background-color:Transparent;
   background-position:bottom ;

     /*  background-image: url(images/office_grid_header.jpg);
     */  

     background-image: url(images/igg_header.gif);


     border:solid 1px #Transparent;
    border-right-color:#F29536;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

Here is the grid after the change is applied:

[image]